# Upgrade issues in django from version 1.7.9 to 1.11.6, unknown command runfcgi

Tags: django, python-2.7, fastcgi

I am working on updating django from 1.7.9 to 1.11.6. While using 1.7.9 we use runfcgi on our production server.

Looks like runfcgi does not exist in 1.11.6. When i do

```
$ python manage.py help
```

runfcgi does not show up.

For someone who uses runfcgi, what is the right path forward for 1.11.6 ? Any recommendation / pointers would be helpful.

Comment: Upgrading straight from 1.7 to 1.11 is a bad idea. You'll miss deprecation warnings. At least upgrade to 1.8 LTS first, even if you miss out 1.9 and 1.10. As for the fastcgi deprecation, you should deploy your project using wsgi instead.

Answer (score 1):

FastCGI support was removed in django 1.9

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/deprecation/

You should not upgrade past django 1.8. If you do, you'll need to find an upgrade path that removes your need for runfcgi.